# Cross-compile to Linux from OS X

Tags: linux, macos, gcc, cross-compiling

I want to compile binaries for a Linux server from an OS X 10.7 + Eclipse build system. This means a GCC cross-compiler. I'm starting from native 4.7.1 and shooting for a host 4.7.1.

Most online instructions are specific to embedded development. I want to use libstdc++-v3 and glibc, which make it a little different.

## What succeeds:

1. Install packages

   ```
   port install gcc47
   export CC=gcc-mp-47
   export LD=ld-mp-47
   export CXX=g++-mp-47
   export CPP=cpp-mp-47

   port install gmake
   ln /opt/local/bin/gmake /opt/local/bin/make

   port install gsed
   ln /opt/local/bin/gsed /opt/local/bin/sed

   port install gawk
   port install autoconf
   port install msgfmt
   ```
2. Make and install binutils-2.22
3. `make all-gcc` and `make install-gcc`

   Used the following config:

   > $ ../gcc/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++ --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local --with-mpc=/opt/local --prefix=/usr/local/cross/linux --target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --disable-nls
4. Point the build environment at the cross-compiler

   ```
   export CC=/usr/local/cross/linux/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc
   export LD=/usr/local/cross/linux/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ld
   export AR=/usr/local/cross/linux/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ar
   export CXX=/usr/local/cross/linux/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++
   export CPP=/usr/local/cross/linux/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-cpp
   ```
5. Build glibc-2.16 using the config

   > ../glibc/configure --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --prefix=/usr/local/cross/linux/ --with-binutils=/usr/local/cross/linux/bin/ --with-headers=/usr/local/cross/linux/include/ libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes libc_cv_ctors_header=yes libc_cv_c_cleanup=yes

## The failure:

glibc build fails before long. This message appears many times:

```
In file included from ./sysdeps/unix/sysdep.h:20:0,
                 from ./sysdeps/unix/x86_64/sysdep.h:18,
                 from sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sysdep.h:22,
                 from <stdin>:1:
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sys/syscall.h:24:24: fatal error: asm/unistd.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

This may be normal, though.

Then it fails to produce `stdio_lim.h`. With `make -d`, I get this:

```
          Successfully remade target file `/Users/dkrauss/Documents/work/glibc-build/csu/abi-tag.h'.
          Considering target file `/Users/dkrauss/Documents/work/glibc-build/bits/stdio_lim.h'.
           File `/Users/dkrauss/Documents/work/glibc-build/bits/stdio_lim.h' does not exist.
           Looking for an implicit rule for `/Users/dkrauss/Documents/work/glibc-build/bits/stdio_lim.h'.
           Trying pattern rule with stem `lim'.
           Trying implicit prerequisite `/Users/dkrauss/Documents/work/glibc-build/bits/stdio_lim.st'.
           Found an implicit rule for `/Users/dkrauss/Documents/work/glibc-build/bits/stdio_lim.h'.
            Considering target file `/Users/dkrauss/Documents/work/glibc-build/bits/stdio_lim.st'.
            Recently tried and failed to update file `/Users/dkrauss/Documents/work/glibc-build/bits/stdio_lim.st'.
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/Users/dkrauss/Documents/work/glibc-build/bits/stdio_lim.st', needed by `/Users/dkrauss/Documents/work/glibc-build/bits/stdio_lim.h'.  Stop.
```

This is the first header it attempts to build in `bits`. There is a file `stdio_lim.h.in`, which is the only `.in` file in its directory. Should some rule be connecting `.st` to `.in`?

Comment: @DietrichEpp Can you clarify? Why should any cross compiler require anything from the host OS? There is something very fishy in principle about the whole toolchain. Is it a staging issue? Like trying to use Linux libraries on the native platform to go from stage 2 to stage 3?

Comment: Seems like it would save you a few days of your life to just install a VM.  Cross-compiling is a real bear.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I have a VM, and in fact I run OS X Snow Leopard as my native platform and the Lion build system is inside another VM. But since I'm working on a team, I'd rather not make the VM part of the build system. It's easier to integrate a cross-compiler. (Edit: After obtaining a cross-compiler, of course!)

Comment: @DietrichEpp Haha, I still think there's something fishy and the linked previous Q mentions that glibc may be impossible to cross compile. A primer on the philosophy on staging would be nice…

Comment: I'm not sure why you are talking about stages.  Are you talking about bootstrap stages?  Because when you are cross compiling, you don't bootstrap, so there are no bootstrapping stages.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yes, thanks for clarifying that. So then back to square 1… why is the target library prerequisite to the cross compiler?

Comment: Exactly which library are you talking about?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15106/discussion-between-potatoswatter-and-dietrich-epp)

Comment: Was there a resolution here?

Comment: @PaulDuBois Nope, I just installed GCC on the server. Obviously that's grand if you have a server, but less so for an embedded system or whatever.

Comment: It is looking for linux kernel headers. asm/unistd.h is part of the linux kernel source.

Answer (score 1):

In order to properly build glibc, you need the header files from a Linux system - probably the kernel headers are sufficient.

This is due to the fact that those headers are needed in any normal build of the software for that system, and the same is no different when cross-compiling.

It's been a long time since I worked on creating cross-compilers, so I can't tell you how to get the build of glibc to see the headers, but I believe it can be done in a straight-forward manner.

Comment: Thanks, I might revisit this soon to verify this answer.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get around to it. At the moment I'm not using Linux for anything. I hopefully will within the next few months.